# jquery dynamic click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dynamic

Can some one help me?
The Idea is to create dynamic buttons with a loop and then use the jquery click function to use one of them

```
//I'm creating dynamic buttons like this:

for(i=0; i<1000; i++){
    $contentBox.append('<button id="add'+ i +'" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Accept</button>');

    //but how would I create the jquery click function?

    $('#add'+i).click(function(e) {....});

    //this does not create 1000 click functions. It only changes the id to the last one so what ever button you click on you will always get the las id
}
```

Comment: You will want to use `$(document).on('click', '#add'+i', function(e){ ... })` for dynamic elements. You can refer to the SO docs about [delegated events](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jquery/1321/events/7666/delegated-events#t=201612170400446260567). I had an example going over adding events handlers to dynamic elements specifically, although it was never accepted/removed. Anyways just change `$('ul')` to `$(document)` in the docs example for it to work in any case.

Comment: use delegates. `$(document).on(click: function(){}, '#add' + i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put `i` in the `....` of your click handler, it won't fix its value to what it was when the click handler was created; rather it will always refer to the variable `i` which takes the value `1000` when you're done looping. Perhaps you could store `i` in an attribute of the button like below (or read it out of the element's id).

```js
$contentBox = $('#content');
$result = $('#result');

for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    $contentBox.append('<button id="add'+ i +'" data-eyeVal="' + i + '" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Accept</button>');

    //but how would I create the jquery click function?

    $('#add'+i).click(function(e) {$result.append('<br/>clicked ' + $(this).attr('data-eyeVal'))});

    //this does not create 1000 click functions. It only changes the id to the last one so what ever button you click on you will always get the las id
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: you the man. Just what I wanted "$(this).attr('data-eyeVal')"

Answer (score 1):

@Spencer's comment is on point - you can use a delegated event. Or, you can simply use the button class:

```
for(i=0; i<1000; i++){
    $contentBox.append('<button id="add'+ i +'" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Accept</button>');

 //Rest of your code
}

//Then attach the event to the class:
$('button.btn-success').click( function(){
//I suspect you'll want the ID so here goes
var buttonID = $(this).attr('id');
//The rest of the fun stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use live function for dynamic button click events. try this

```
$('#add'+i).live("click", function(){
  // codings
});
```

Comment: [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated and removed since `1.9`.